# Hibernate 5 on GAE: NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.StringRefAddr is a restricted class

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, hibernate-5.x

After migration from Hibernate 4.3.11.Final to 5.0.6.Final I receive the following exception:

```
[INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in xxx.xxx.configuration.AppConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.StringRefAddr is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:272)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:225)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:216)

[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.StringRefAddr is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getReference(SessionFactoryImpl.java:877)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory$TypeScopeImpl.injectSessionFactory(TypeFactory.java:62)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectSessionFactory(TypeFactory.java:100)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.scope(TypeResolver.java:37)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:249)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
[INFO]  ... 38 more
```

StringRefAddr is a restricted class I know, but is there any trick to run Hibernate 5 somehow? I am using GAE 1.9.30.

Comment: This is nothing to do with hibernate-5.0.6 as the implementation where its breaking down is similar to what we have @hibernate-4.3.11. We left with the GAE library that you using. Have you upgarted that as well ? Whats the version you currently using ??

Comment: I am using the newest one: 1.9.30

Answer (score 0):

I just shared details on the GAE implementation around black & white lists along with the hack that one need to do get around this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752399/google-app-engine-jre-class-black-list/34432554#34432554).